# can I add my script/apis to my Django project? If so how can I do this

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I am building a Django web app, and I want to allow users to search for their desired crypto currency and then return the price. I plan on getting the price from coinbase or some other site that already presents this information. How would I go about this. I figure I would have to wrote the script to get the price under views.py. What would be the best approach? Can I add a web scrapping script that already does this to django? Or would I have to connect say coinbases api to my Django project. If so how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking at using an API from a service to get these prices then `Request` is something you can look at.

If you're looking at scrapping the data from a page, then you'll probably want to look at [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or [scrapy](https://scrapy.org) or one step further [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)

As for where you call it, that's on you. if it's data that you're always going to need, then you could look at runnning your script as a task or worker so you're always getting an up-to-date price. Otherwise you could trigger the script and wait for the response to come back. Lot's of draw backs to both of these, and I'm guessing if the site doesn't provide an API for getting the info you need through a managed endpoint they will probably block your requests if you make too many of them.

but that's a starter for 10